# How to compile all design images as used in website design?

Tags: images, design, png, psd

I am just coming into a new web design role and so far I can find no central repository of all images as used on the website.  I have previously, at some point in the design process, inserted all design images (global buttons, layout images, background gradients etc) into a PNG file - sometimes multiple PNG files if warranted.  (Please note that I am not talking about content images (such as photos that would be used in an article), just the images that are part of the design.)

Before I go about the usual task of compiling all images into a PSD/PNG, just to see if there are other, more manageable ways.

My question here is, how do you store all of the images that you use in a website? Do you have a central repository (PSD/PNG) file for all of your buttons, all of your gradients or is that unnecessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my setup:

The list of all theme images does exist and it is called the css file.

The css file references images in a folder called images and content images are kept elsewhere in a content folder.

To get a list of the images referenced in the css you can use command line 'grep' to list all of the lines containing 'url'.

As for PSD originals, since much is done in layers and saved out separately, I just have a folder on my local PC named after the project to keep them in. That works for me - no fancy versioning or anything so advanced.